# Dynamically setting case value with switchee

Tags: segments, switchee

I'm wanting to dynamically populate a switchee value, I've tried using an embed, but it seems the parse order means this won't work so I'm looking for aternative ideas, this is the code we've tried:

```
{exp:switchee variable="{segment_1}" parse="inward"}

    {case value="{embed='site/_school-list'}"}
        {redirect="/contribute/school/{segment_1}"}
    {/case}

    {case default="yes"}
        Otherwise go here   
    {/case}

{/exp:switchee}
```

Basically I want to automatically pull out all of the entries from the school channel and get their {url_title}, then check it against {segment_1}.

The code in the embed is:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="schools" dynamic="no" limit="99999"}{url_title}|{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Which is outputting correctly when tested.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you could easily use Stash to pass the entry ids as a variable, you shouldn't.

To create the variable would mean iterating over the entire list of entries in a channel. That's expensive just for a simple routing operation.

Assuming this is being run on your site's default index template, and you have strict 404s disabled, why not just redirect if `segment_1` exists at all?

```
{if segment_1 != ""}
 {redirect="/contribute/school/{segment_1}"}
{/if}
```

Your template `contribute/school` should take care of 404s using a channel entries tag with parameters `require_entry="yes"` and `{if no_results}{redirect="404"}{/if}`